# Struts Option tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, struts

I wanted tooltip on Html:options element, when mouseover to each, displays opition name of that property.

```
 <logic:present name = "xxx"> 
        <td id = "" align="" width="" rowspan = "">
        <html:select multiple="" size="" property=""  styleId="" style="" onmouseover="showToolTips()">
        <html:options collection="" name="" property="" labelProperty=""/>
        </html:select>    
        </td>
    </logic:present>
```

tried with JScript, showToolTips(), also dint work
is there anyway around tooltip inside html:options tag or html:select tag
thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<html:options collection="" name="" property="" labelProperty=""  title="Tooltip"/>
```